# Проекция клавиатуры

Tags: windows, клавиатура, поиск-программ

Подскажите существует ли под Windows софт типа небольшой экранной карты клавиатуры чтобы видеть на ней нажатия клавиш на реальной клавиатуре (как это реализовано в тренажерах "слепой печати")?